# Error while resizing the subviews

Tags: ios, uiview

I have 2 views inside my main view of the view controller in following way:

[image]

My requirement is very simple, I want to resize my view2 to occupy complete view based on some condition. Currently, I don't care about that condition and simply want to resize view2 inside my `viewDidLoad`. Here is the code I am using.

```
    CGRect newFrame = self.view2.frame;
    [self.view2 removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view1 removeFromSuperview];                
    newFrame.size.width =703;// width of main view
    newFrame.size.height =632;// height of main view
    newFrame.origin.x=0;
    newFrame.origin.y=0;
    [self.view2 setFrame:newFrame];       
    [self.view addSubview:self.view2];
```

In the above code `view` is an outlet to main view of the view controller. `view2` is an outlet to my view2  and `view1` to view1 in the above photo. My view1 is has background color as black and view2 has background color as red. The app works fine without the above code of resizing but when I run the above resizing code I get an empty screen.

Someone please help me find out my mistake.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should not try setting the frame of any sub view in viewDidLoad(). You won't be getting correct frame size which you did set from storyboard in `viewDidLoad()`. Try `NSLog(NSStringFromCGRect(self.view1.frame)` in viewDidLoad(). The correct place to make changes in frames of sub views in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

Try this in viewDidLayoutSubviews:

```
CGRect newFrame = view2.frame
NSLog(NSStringFromCGRect(newFrame))
newFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(0.0)
newFrame.origin.y = CGFloat(0.0)
newFrame.size.width = CGFloat(703.0)
newFrame.size.height = CGFloat(632.0)
view2.frame = newFrame
NSLog(NSStringFromCGRect(newFrame))
```

Comment: The result is still an empty screen. No change.

Comment: My frame values are correct. My guess is the problem is there while adding the view back to super view.

Comment: Ohk but why do you want to remove them from superView just for changing view frame?

Comment: Yes, if I am not removing it first from superview then no changes are happening.

Comment: The above code will work even without removing from superView

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, No need to remove the views from main view.If you want to resize the view just try like this instead of above all code.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
     self.view2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400);
}
```

EDIT:

use the code in above method instead of viewDidLoad.

Comment: Not removing the view from superview is doing no change at all. It is loading things as it is there in storyboard.

Comment: No need to remove the view.Try my edited code.It's working fine for me.If it is not.just post your latest code.

Comment: I tried the exact same code you gave me. `self.view2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 703, 632);` inside my `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. But, it is loading things as it is from storyboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87155/discussion-between-exception-and-vishnuvardhan).